# Trying to figure out how to pass multiple Values Via onchange=""

Tags: php, ajax

Hey i have multiple dropdown selections that i want to grab the values of. The general idea is to get the values from each individual dropdown to pass for a ajax call. Heres the 3 code snippets. The first 2 are the values i want to collect and the third is to pass the calls. Any help is appreciated. thank you.

```
    <div id="year"  class="dropdownmenu styled-select">
    <label>Year:</label>
        <select name="year" id="yearlist" onchange="getId(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select Year</option>

        <?php       
        $query = "select distinct(Year) from websitemasterlist order by Year ASC";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        foreach($results as $info) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $info[Year]; ?>"><?php echo $info[Year]; ?></option>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>    

    <div id="make"  class="dropdownmenu styled-select">
    <label>Make:</label>
        <select name="make" id="makelist" onchange="getId2(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select Make</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="model"  class="dropdownmenu styled-select">
    <label>Model:</label>
        <select name="model" id="modellist" onchange="getId3(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select Model</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

heres the code to collect that information i was wondering how i could collect both the year and make when 1 is changed.

```
function getId(val){
    jQuery.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://comugg.com/getdata.php",
                data: "year="+val,
                success:function(data){
                    jQuery("#makelist").html(data);
                }
    });
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly .. OnChange you should be able to call multiple functions ....  IE  `onchange="getId2(this.value); getId3(this.value);"`

Comment: where is the javascript?

Comment: Format the code logically and it will help you

Comment: i updated the javascript. my mistake.

Comment: @ Zak im trying to to get the values from different dropdowns. for example, in this case.... i want onchange=getid(this.value) and also the selected value from make .

Comment: cleaned up code format a bit for ease of reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your function like this to post more data. More info and a jquery example here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#example-0

```
function getId(val){
    var modelVariable = $( '#model:selected' ).val();
    jQuery.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://comugg.com/getdata.php",
                data: {
                    year : val,
                    make : makeVariable
                },
                success:function(data){
                    jQuery("#makelist").html(data);
                }
    });
}
```